# Excel VBA Compile Error Cant Find Library or Project

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, userform

I am getting this error when I try and run an excel Userform on any other computer than the computer that developed the form.

Compile Error:

Cant Find Library or Project

Here is the code giving the error.

```
Private Sub txt_Search_Change()
On Error Resume Next
If Me.txt_Search.Text = "" Then
Call Fill_List
Exit Sub
End If

Me.ListBox1.Clear
Dim r, last_row As Integer
last_row = Sheet2.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To last_row
    a = Len(Me.txt_Search.Text) 
    If UCase(Left(Sheet2.Cells(r, criterion).Value, a)) = UCase(Me.txt_Search.Text) Then
    With Me.ListBox1
    .AddItem Sheet2.Cells(r, "A").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "B").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "C").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "D").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "E").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "F").Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = Sheet2.Cells(r, "G").Value
    End With
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Ive tried changing the code around a bit and nothing a did fixed the problem. Always the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`

[image: References]

Easiest way to go about this is to [create a form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOzqI.png) in VBA